# How to update string column of a shapefile GRASS GIS

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis, string

I'm relatively new in GRASS GIS and I want to update a column of a shapefile.

I use GRASS GIS (version 7.8.6 on Ubuntu 20.04 .4 LTS), not the GRASS extension in QGIS.

I'm workin on a shapefile. In this file there is a column that specifies a label.
I would like to update the column replacing the space in the string with undercores ( _ ).

Either updating the existing column or creating a new one are fine with me.

What I want is something like that:

| label | new_label |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C D | C_D |
| E F G | E_F_G |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more related to string manipulations than about GRASS. Since the SQL backend for GRASS vectors is sqlite, you can use an SQL query to remove or replace the spaces in one column like so:

```
# A sample vector layer:
v.db.select points
cat|label
1|A A
2|A B
3|A B C 
4|C C
5|D C B A

# Add a new column to hold labels without spaces
v.db.addcolumn points col="new_label varchar(25)"

# Now run SQL query to populate that column
db.execute sql="UPDATE points SET new_label=REPLACE(label, ' ', '_')"

# Results:
v.db.select points
cat|label|new_label
1|A A|A_A
2|A B|A_B
3|A B C |A_B_C_
4|C C|C_C
5|D C B A|D_C_B_A
```